# Компиляция с ошибкой в JavaMail

Tags: java, android, javamail

При компиляции кода подчеркивается `true`. Что тут не так?

Вот лог ошибки:
`Error:(46, 86) error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to CharSequence`

Вот фрагмент кода:
`protected void onPreExecute() {
     waitingDialog = progressDialog.show(ExtendedMail.this, Отправляем сообщение...", true);
        }`

---

Так же подчеркиваются строки выделенные жирным шрифтом..

Вот лог ошибки:
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

Вот фрагмент кода:

title =**((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();**
text = **((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();**

text1 =**((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText().toString();**

---

Вот сам код:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.projectsend.MailSenderClass;
import com.example.projectsend.R;

public class ExtendedMail extends Activity {

Context mainContext;

String title;
String text;
String text1;
String from;
String where;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); mainContext = this;

    Button butse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    butse.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { sender_mail_async async_sending = new sender_mail_async();
            async_sending.execute();
        }
    });
}

private class sender_mail_async extends asyncTask<object, string, boolean> {
    progressDialog waitingDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        waitingDialog = progressDialog.show(ExtendedMail.this, "Отправляем сообщение...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {
        waitingDialog.dismiss();
        toast.makeText(mainContext, "Отправлено", toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Activity)mainContext).finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean doInBackground(object... params) {

        try {
            title = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
            text = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();
            text1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText().toString();
            from = "отправитель"; where = "получатель";

            MailSenderClass sender = new MailSenderClass("отправитель", "пароль");
            sender.sendMail(title, text, text1, from, where);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            toast.makeText(mainContext, "Ошибка отправки сообщения!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: это у вас опечатка - `progressDialog waitingDialog;`?

Comment: Нет, а что тут не так?

Comment: да так какого типа объявляется ссылка `waitingDialog`? - `progressDialog`, нет такого класса!!! `ProgressDialog`- есть, `progressDialog`- нет.

Comment: Странно при компиляции ошибок нет, я думал, что это не имеет значения. Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: если бы ошибок не было, сдается мне, вы бы сюда не обратились...

Comment: Я имел ввиду ошибок с правильностью написания класса.

Comment: ну значит компилятор обнаружил ошибки выше по стеку вызова и до этой ошибки еще не дошел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данная ошибки говорит о том, что у `ProgressDialog` нет метода `show()`, который удовлетворял бы вашему набору параметров:

```
show(Context context, CharSequence title, boolean cancelable)
```

Есть вот такие варианты вызова:

```
show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message)
show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable)
show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener cancelListener)
show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate)
```

[ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)